# How to add a non-English help file to a third-party vim plugin?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am using vim8.1 ,and installed nerdtree plugin. The nerdtree plugin provides an english help file , i had an non-English help file , how should i install this non-English help file to view  non-English help information in vim ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained at [`:help help-translated`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/helphelp.txt.html#help-translated); it works the same for core Vim help and plugin help files (which follow the same format and conventions).

Basically, you put the translated document next to the original English one, with a file extension that consists of the *two-letter language code* plus `x`, so `*.itx` for Italian, `*.zhx` for Chinese, and so on.

Then run [`:helptags`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/helphelp.txt.html#%3Ahelptags), and with the right language of [`'helplang'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27helplang%27), the default `:help` should pick up your translation.

#### Example

The [AutoComplPop plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/AutoComplPop/blob/master/doc/acp.jax) ships with a Japanese translation.